# Float to string with at least one digit after period

Tags: c#

How do I format a Float to String:

1 => "1.0"

1.12345 => "1.12345"

Instead of:

```
 String.Format("{0:0.0}", 123.0); // Limit amount of digits
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of {0:0.0}? Are you looking for an alternative to string.Format() or are you claiming that your above example doesn't work, because I believe it does.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I am searching for something to replace {0:0.0}, but I tested it. It limit it to only one digit after the period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there a *maximum* limit to the number of digits?

You can instead use:

```
String.Format("{0:0.0#####}", floatVal)
```

You can extend the `#` out to whatever you want/consider reasonable. Following the `.` of the format specifier, a `0` indicates the decimal precision place should *always* be shown, while `#` indicates it should be shown if present.

Comment: It is a very good option. I am not in control of how accurate they want it, but I can just add a lot of # if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 1.45783f;
string result = f.ToString("f2");
```

Comment: Sorry, did not work for me: f=1.0 => "1.00", f=1.2345 => "1.23"

Answer (score 0):

toString() can take an IFormatProvider which will allow you to format various data types to other formats.

```
float f = 1.45783f;
string result = f.ToString("f2");
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. FYI: f.ToString(format) and String.Format(format, f) are bascially identical.